# jpa criteria subquery for count with where clause

Tags: java, jpa, subquery, eclipselink, criteria

This is the query I neede,

```
SELECT
    t0.traderDeclarationNumber AS a1, t0.referenceNumber AS a2,(SELECT COUNT(t1.userid)
FROM
    log_table t1
WHERE
    (t1.userid = 'user')) FROM status_table t0
```

I wrote the criteria query,

```
    final CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    final Root<StatusTable> statusRoot = criteriaQuery.from(StatusTable.class);
    Subquery<Long> subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    final Root<LogTable> logRoot = subQuery.from(LogTable.class);
    subQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(logRoot.get("userid")));
    subQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(logRoot.get("userid"), "user"));
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(
            statusRoot.get("traderDeclarationNumber"),
            statusRoot.get("referenceNumber"),
            subQuery.getSelection());
    final TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<Object[]> objectsList=typedQuery.getResultList();
```

But while running the code, the where clause not applying in query. The generated query is

> SELECT t0.traderDeclarationNumber AS a1, t0.referenceNumber AS
>   a2,(SELECT COUNT(t1.userid) FROM log_table t1) FROM status_table t0

Only the count(userid) is in query. Please help me to find out the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your subquery is _not_ correlated to the outer SQL query, which perhaps looks a bit strange.  Is that the query you really want to run here?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the SQL that your chosen JPA provider generates for that criteria? And maybe mention which JPA provider it is ...

Comment: I am using eclipselink

Comment: "SELECT
    t0.traderDeclarationNumber AS a1, t0.referenceNumber AS a2,(SELECT COUNT(t1.userid)
FROM
    log_table t1) FROM status_table t0" .This is the query generated

Comment: Raise a bug on your JPA provider if it is not adding where conditions when you asked it to. Your call to `where` on the subquery is perfectly valid.

Comment: Why are you passing subQuery.getSelection() instead of just the subQuery itself?  This gives you what you passed in to subQuery.select, and is why you aren't seeing your where clause in the executed query.

Comment: Hello Chris, ":javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.SubQueryImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.SelectionImpl". This is the error I got when I passed subQuery itself.